# Closure : a function that returns the value of its previous call

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a function that returns the value of its previous call using closure. The first time function is called, it will return None. I'm not sure how to update last_in from one call to another.

```
def last_in(x):
    last_in = [None]

    def get():
        temp = last_in[0]
        last_in[0] = x
        # print(last_in)
        return temp
    return get()
```

For example, `print(last_in(1),last_in(2),last_in(3))` should print: `None 1 2`

Comment: Why you have function name and list name both as `last_in`?

Comment: I would check out [PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) as well

Comment: Is this purely for learning purposes?

Comment: for learning purposes

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your approach is that whenever you call `last_in`, i.e. the "outer" function, the previous value stored in `last_in` (the array, not the function) is reset to `None`. Instead, the outer function should be called only once so that the value is not reset each time you call it.

Not sure what you need this for, but I think it would make sense to create a decorator function for this, i.e. a function modifying an existing function. This way, all the storing-and-retrieving-the-last-result can be done in the decorator without cluttering the actual function. The outer function (the decorator) is called only once, and the original function is replaced with the decorated version that will correctly retrieve the stored value.

```
def return_previous(f):
    f.last_result = None
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        res = f.last_result
        f.last_result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return _f

@return_previous
def some_function(x):
    return x**2

print(some_function(1), some_function(2), some_function(3))
# None 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the solution that @tobias_k provides, but here is another alternative which conforms to the current organization/structure of your code.

```
def last_in(x):
    def get():
        temp = last_in.__dict__.get('prev', None)
        last_in.__dict__['prev'] = x
        return temp
    return get()

print(last_in(1),last_in(2),last_in(3))

None 1 2
```

Comment: Could you please explain the last_in.__dict__.get('prev', None) part ? unfortunately, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: that is simply performing a `get` on a dictionary, if you have ever used a dictionary before it's the same as `my_dict[a]`. if you are wondering more about what an object's `__dict__` method is, you can read more here --> https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2016/06/09/the-magic-behind-attribute-access-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight deviation from the request since it requires a second keyword argument but you could take advantage of the fact that default arguments are only set once (see [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)) to do something like this:

```
def last_in(x, __last=[None]):
    last = __last[0]
    __last[0] = x
    return last
```

`__last` is set once when the function is declared and since it is mutable, you can update it at each function call and the updated value will persist between calls.